# Use 3D View Google Map in Leaflet plugin

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, leaflet.draw, dc.leaflet.js

I Use Leaflet Map Plugin. i Write this code for create and load google map tiles in LeafLet

```
 var map = L.map('map').setView([31.2744015, 48.7251283], 18);

    // load a tile layer

    //Satellite:
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
    }).addTo(map);
```

this code work fine. But I Want Load another google Map option in this plugin Like 3D View map
[image]

But will this be done?
thanks for help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. Loading map tiles from Google using just a `L.TileLayer` contravenes the terms&conditions of Google Maps (the part about "accessing the content **only through** the Google Maps **API**"). Do not be surprised if Google gets angry at that.

   As pointed out in the answers to the question «[Leaflet Map API with Google Satellite Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394190/leaflet-map-api-with-google-satellite-layer)» , look in the   [Leaflet plugins list](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html). In particular, [GoogleMutant](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant) might be of interest.
2. As of now, Leaflet is able to display 2D maps **only**. There are no plans to make it display oblique imagery, or provide tilt capabilities.

   If you need these features, you might want to have a look at other web mapping libraries, such as https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/ or https://cesiumjs.org/. These can handle more degrees of camera freedom, and some degree of terrain elevation display.

Answer (score -2):

https://labs.mapbox.com/bites/00093/

pls see the source code of it , as

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        $('.rotating').attr('style','-webkit-transform:rotateZ('+angle+'deg);-moz-transform:rotateZ('+angle+'deg);-moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.75s;');
        if ($('.rotating').length>0) $('.pivotmarker').attr('style','-webkit-transform: rotateY('+angle+'deg);-moz-transform: rotateY('+angle+'deg);-moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.75s;');
        angle=angle*-1;
    },1500);
```

may it help

Comment: jquery makes any code completely unreadable, avoid, it's over, it's been obsolete for over 10 years now